# Retrieve user id from Siteminder smsession

Tags: userid, siteminder

Our system is a gateway interacting with Siteminder for authentication and connecting to back end systems. Siteminder is returning SMSESSION and SMIDENTITY in the header. How to retrieve the userid from SMSESSION. The format is as below:
SMSESSION=dQtTYNjolqkVPoblyV2iUYzlaffxweO7jwHdbC8R8HCRzyuR2E6we22hBEdfOquw4Wx4V2Ly6tuTq7DctZXBpiUVOqYr1htSKExdDauUYD0Eh+jmdw9yBSSjkUm/nlDd6iFizN2zeyBAGda7jgHbyvKCB0T54ZrFFEMTd1jdJfiOJS0q6c

I have tried to take the encoded string manually and decode it but its not getting me the user id. How to get the userid from SMSESSION?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you decode smsession cookie?

Answer (score 6):

I believe SMSESSION cookie is encrypted by the agent, you won't be able to do much with it.  You'll have to work with the external SiteMinder support team to ask them to add the SM_USER or other headers.  It is a part of SiteMinder configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The user ID can be found in a default SiteMinder header tageed "SM_USER"

Comment: Thanks, but the response does not contain any header, SM_USER. Its an external system and do not have much control over that system.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SM_USER from the response.getHeaderNames(), use the following script in your index.jsp:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

<%
    java.util.Enumeration names = request.getHeaderNames();

    String SM_USER = "";

    while(names.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String name = (String)names.nextElement();
        if(name.contains("SM_USER"))
        {
                 SM_USER = request.getHeader("SM_USER");
        }
    }


%>  

    var SM_USER = '<%= SM_USER %>';     

</script>
```

Then you can access the SM_USER value from window.SM_USER